# Category in a private header in Static Library not found by Swift app code

Tags: objective-c, swift, static-libraries, objective-c-category, private-header

I am trying redo an objective C app in Swift, Both the Swift app and Objective C app will use the same static library which is written in Objective C. I have a category inside a private header in the static library. The objective C app has no problem in accessing the category method but the swift app cannot. How can I make this work without making the header file as a public header